# regular expression to represent two of the same vowel in a row

Tags: regex, grep

I try to write regular expression to represent two of the same vowel in a row.

I know this code grep a, but how about e,i,o,u
    (a[aeiou]{2})

Should I'write the codes as like that to grep tow of the same vowel?

```
(a[aeiou]{2}|i[aeiou]{2}|i[aeiou]{2}|o[aeiou]{2}|u[aeiou]{2})
```

Comment: Your regex isn't even close. It would probably be easier to help you learn if you explained what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a group reference :

```
([aeiou])\1
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/dI9kB9/1

Comment: Doesn't match anyone. `egrep '/([aeiou])\1/' grep.txt`

Comment: @Alex Just remove the forwardslashes!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
aa|ee|ii|oo|uu
```

The bar ( | ) is used for "or".

So this reads as:
aa OR ee OR ii OR oo OR uu

It is also known as "alternation".
See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

It has an example where you can search for dog|cat|mouse|fish, which I would read as "dog OR cat OR mouse OR fish".

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: I have added some more explanation :)